# Forced to specify relation values in resolvers with ApolloServer and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, apollo, prisma, apollo-server

I am using Apollo Server with TypeScript types generation.

The GraphQL type I am working on at the moment is the following.

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  email: String!
  name: String!
  posts: [Post!]!
  reactions: [Reaction!]!
}

type Query {
  me: User
}
```

NOTE: the `!` after the arrays is voluntary. I don't want those to be potentially `null`, I want them to be arrays that are worse case empty.

In my base query resolver, I implement `me` as following.

```
  me() {
    return {
      id: '123',
      name: 'Joe',
      email: 'joe@example.com',
    };
  },
```

I am leaving out `posts` and `reactions`, as they will be resolved down the chain by the `user` resolver object (which is implemented, returning `[]` in both cases for the moment).

Doing that does not make the type system happy, as the `me()` function in the query resolver is typed `me?: Resolver<Maybe<ResolversTypes['User']>, ParentType, ContextType>;`, which -- long story short -- has to return a `User`.

```
// Code generated by Apollo Server
export type User = {
  __typename?: 'User';
  email: Scalars['String']['output'];
  id: Scalars['ID']['output'];
  name: Scalars['String']['output'];
  posts: Array<Post>;
  reactions: Array<Reaction>;
};
```

Here, the `posts` and `reactions` arrays are required.

Back to the query resolvers, if I implement `me()` like following ...

```
  me() {
    return {
      id: '123',
      name: 'Joe',
      email: 'joe@example.com',
      posts: [],
      reactions: [],
    };
  },
```

..., then the type system is happy. Considering the types being generated, I understand why.

My first question is the following: are those generated types wrong? Since I am allowed to not specify some values of my return type to let the resolvers chain do its work, the generated types should be expecting something like `Partial<User>`.

Additional "what the...?" moment: returning `undefined` for those 2 properties ...

```
  me() {
    return {
      id: '123',
      name: 'Joe',
      email: 'joe@example.com',
      posts: undefined,
      reactions: undefined,
    };
  },
```

... actually works and makes TS happy, even though `User` states that those are mendatory and cannot be `null` or `undefined`.

Proving `null` also makes TS happy.

I am wondering of course first if I am not *holding something wrong*.

But it feels like the generated types should be allowing you to not provide all values, to let them be resolved further down the chain.

If I force-typecast `as User`, if also works and the resolvers chain calls the `posts()` of my `userResolvers` object (as it should).

This example may be trivial, but then when you return an array of `User`, and you get it from the database (eg: using *Prisma*), I have for now to `.map` all of them to insert the missing `posts: undefined, reactions: undefined` to make the type system happy, and that despite the examples I find of *Apollo Server* and *Prisma* being integrated together without those map.

I should be able to, in the end, just do

```
  async me(_parent, _args, { db }) {
    return await db.user.findFirstOrThrow({ where: { email: 'joe@example.com' } });
  },
```

without having to

```
  async me(_parent, _args, { db }) {
    const me = await db.user.findFirstOrThrow({ where: { email: 'joe@example.com' } });
    return { ...me, posts: undefined, reactions: undefined };
  },
```

I am using the latest versions of all NPM packages (as of November 19th, 2023).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: The answer [is here](https://the-guild.dev/blog/better-type-safety-for-resolvers-with-graphql-codegen#whats-next).

It is possible to specify a default mapper in the configuration to `Partial<{T}>`.

```
// codegen.ts
import type { CodegenConfig } from '@graphql-codegen/cli';

const config: CodegenConfig = {
  overwrite: true,
  schema: './src/typeDefs.graphql',
  generates: {
    'src/__generated__/graphql.ts': {
      plugins: ['typescript', 'typescript-resolvers'],
    },
  },
  config: {
    useIndexSignature: true,
    contextType: '../context#Context',
    defaultMapper: 'Partial<{T}>', //  This line here!
  },
};

export default config;
```

That will cause the *TypeScript* generated types to go from

```
User: ResolverTypeWrapper<User>;
```

to

```
User: ResolverTypeWrapper<Partial<User>>;
```

Then, your resolvers are allowed to return a `User` without providing its `posts` or `reactions` attributes and let the resolver chain do its magic (calling the proper `UsersResolver` if the query asks for that information).